# Ruby type conversion arbitrary by needed class

Tags: ruby, class

Example. I have two variables with random classes:

```
first = 12345    #Fixnum
second = "12345" #String
```

Can i convert second var to class identical of first variable?

i can do it with if block:

```
if first.class == Fixnum
 second = second.to_i
elsif first.class == String
 # do nothing
end
```

but, can a do it simple, instead if or case constructions?

Comment: What's wrong with simply do `to_f`, without the condition?

Comment: class of first and second variables can be other than Fixnum, and i don't know it until want compare two variables. Some what i want: second = to_class(first)

Comment: That's not what you're doing. `to_f` doesn't convert to `Fixnum`. You want `to_i`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `case` statement.

```
result = case first
  when Fixnum
    second.to_i
  when Array
    [second]
  else
    second
end
```

However, if you start to have several values, you may want to consider a better design pattern. For example, you can wrap `second` in custom object types that properly implement a casting technique.

```
result = first.class.cast(second)
```

Comment: not worked for me: NoMethodError: undefined method `cast' for Fixnum:Class

Comment: @SergeijBelevskij The `cast` was just an example of a possible interface. It won't work unless you write the code to make it working. The first example, instead, will work.

Comment: @SimoneCarletti it's `case first` not `case first.class`